# Bootstrap 4 - Nav Tabs and Pills- Showing bullet point

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-4

I am currently working in an ASP.Net MVC Core 2.0 Web application that in production has bootstrap 3.3.7 installed, however we are looking to make a jump up to bootstrap 4.3.1.

However, I have an issue where the Nav tabs, and Nav Pills that I am using all show the

bullet point

in the tab as shown in the image below.

The code I am working with where the issue presents on the nav tabs is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            @{
                var firstTab = true;
                foreach (var year in Model.UniqueYears)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(academicYear))
                    {
                        //If there are any scheduled courses that are associated with that delivery method via name, then show the tab.
                        if (Model.ScheduledCourses.Where(scheduledCourse => scheduledCourse.year == year.Split(' ')[0]).Any())
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item @(firstTab ? "active" : "")">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#year-@year.GenerateSlug()" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">@academicYear</a>
                            </li>
                            firstTab = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </ul>
```

and the result is as per the image below.

[image]

I would be most grateful if anyone can help me with what I need to change in order to remove the

bullet point

I have already tried adding in basic \ plain \ example code from

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs

however, just get the same issue.

The order in which the css items are introduced in the Layout is

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/slick-lightbox/dist/slick-lightbox.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/@(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.ToLower()).css" />
```

and js is pulled in like below

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

Any and all help very much appreciated.

Comment: The CSS 'nav' class on the <ul> is what removes the bullet point from the nav tabs. Something must be overriding that. Open your webpage in the Chrome browser, then right-click on the nav tab. Then select 'Inspect Element'. The inspector will open. Look in Styles to see what CSS class is overriding the Bootstrap nav class.

Comment: This sounds like you have some css in yoru site.css or other files that is overriding the bootstrap ul styles.  Need to review those files and use the inspector to see what is causing it.

Comment: in the inspector I have removed all css objects and its still there, so dont think its tht, plus it wasnt there with bootstrap 3.3.x but it now with 4.3.1

Comment: Bootstrap `nav nav-tabs` must have from itself style `list-style: none`, so check with the inspector if this style is overriding

Comment: There is a class called `list-unstyled` you can try to add to your `ul`

Comment: @bhmahler you were right, in the app that I am working in, just started on it last week is 3 years old and the CSS is a little (lot) spaghetti...